Galois connections give rise to complete lattices
I am reading Introduction to Lattices and Order, second edition, by Davey and Priestly. On page 161, it says

Every Galois connection $(^\rhd,^\lhd)$ gives rise to a pair of closure operators, $^{\rhd\lhd}$ and $^{\lhd\rhd}$, and thence to an isomorphic pair of complete lattices (7.27)

What is the pair of complete lattices here? From 7.27, we get $P_c$ and $Q_{k}^{\partial}$ and they are isomorphic, but I don't think they are complete lattices. One counter-example is that taking $P=Q$ to be an ordered set that is not a lattice, and let $^\rhd,^\lhd:P\to P$ be the identity map.

7.27 Let $(^\rhd,^\lhd)$ be a Galois connection between ordered sets $P$ and $Q^{\partial}$. Then
(i) $c:= ^{\rhd\lhd}:P\to P$ and $k:=^{\lhd\rhd}:Q\to Q$ are closure operators.
(ii) Let $P_c:=\{p\in P| p^{\rhd\lhd}=p\}$ and $Q_{k}:=\{q\in Q|q^{\lhd\rhd}=q\}$. Then $^\rhd:P_c\to Q_{k}^{\partial}$ and $^\lhd:Q_{k}^{\partial}\to P_{c}$ are mutually inverse order-isomorphisms.


I think the book is not completely clear on that, or at least I was also not able to find the justification.
Now, when you have a Galois connection $(\varphi,\psi)$ between posets $P$ and $Q$, the complete lattices that arise are not of elements $p \in P$ such that $\psi\varphi(p)=p$ and elements $q \in Q$ such that $\varphi\psi(q)=q$, but rather between sets of such elements, like $A \subseteq P$ such that $\psi\varphi(A)=A$, and likewise for $B \subseteq Q$.
In the case of the example you came up with, where $P=Q$ and $\varphi=\psi=\mathrm{id}$, the resulting complete lattice is the power set of $P$.

So the complete lattices are $\mathcal{P}(P_c)$ and $\mathcal{P}(Q_{k}^{\partial})$. And $A\mapsto \varphi(A)$, $B\mapsto \psi(B)$ are the maps. They are isomorphic. Thanks!
